# Wordpress "Stylesheet is missing" error. Shopify theme to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes, shopify, stylesheet

Can I extract and upload my customized shopify theme to wordpress? I spoke with shopify support and they told me that theme files are all similar to wordpress themes and that they just might work with wordpress.

I extracted my shopify theme files and uploaded them to cpanel wordpress themes but I got "Stylesheet is missing" error. Is there any fix for this issue?

Theme files image at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMubN.png
I extracted theme files with shopifys "Download theme file" feature Image at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuW18.png
I can send you theme zip folder if you wish (just a test theme anyway).

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Do some research: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/

Comment: Alright mate. Found my answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all your style.css file needs to be in root directory, you can read more about WordPress Template Hierarchy over [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

And it must contain [following](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/) info at the top

and by looking at your file structure i don't think it will work as is.

Comment: It great you want to help, but please don't answer such low-quality questions.  Instead, you can leave some "tips" in a comment.

Comment: i was unable to leave comment due to points needed to add comment.